# New to R Studio. library(devtools) not loading. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’. Is there a way out?

Tags: r, devtools

I am new to RStudio.
I am trying to load devtools so that I can install packages from github
So basically what I am trying to do is:

1. install.packages("devtools")
2. load(devtools)
3. install_github("author/package")

Ideally these three steps should have gone through without a hitch. But this is what happened.

```
    library(devtools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package ‘backports’ does not have a namespace
```

What do I do? I am completely new to this.

Here's the whole console

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Rohan Gopakumar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
devtools  2.3.0  2.3.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘devtools’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 373604 bytes (364 KB)
downloaded 364 KB

* installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
** package 'devtools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package 'backports' does not have a namespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/Rohan Gopakumar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/devtools'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Rohan Gopakumar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Rohan Gopakumar\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpasaxsp\downloaded_packages’
> library(devtools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package ‘backports’ does not have a namespace
```

Comment: Install `backports` first.